# How to send dynamic form's data using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've multiple `dynamic forms` in a single web page like as follows

```
<form name='login' id='login_1'>
<input type='text' name='username'/>
<input type='password' name='pwd'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit_1' value='Login'/>
</form>
<form name='login' id='login_2'>
<input type='text' name='username'/>
<input type='password' name='pwd'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit_2' value='Login'/>
</form>
.......
.......
```

Here `id's` are dynamic,suppose if user's enters data in second form and submits then I need to send second(only) form data to server without using third party `jQuery plugins`,here I'm unable to select `submit button id` properly.

Is it secure process to send data using `serializeArray();`, especially for login process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have form's without files than it is just fine to serialize form inputs.

You can catch the submit event and pass data's using ajax

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   var action = $(this).attr("action");
   //You Can add an input type hidden to store form id, in case you need it at Server
   $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'>");
   var data = $(this).serializeArray();
   $.post(action,data,function(data){
     //server response
     console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: what if i have to submit form with file via ajax using a dynamic form, with other input fields details ??

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to attach a function $('form').submit() and put your ajax POST to server code there...

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var thisForm = $(this);
    alert(thisForm.find("input[type=submit]").attr("id"));

    // perform ajax call here
    // $(ajax). ---

    return false;
});
```

**Here is a demo** http://www.bootply.com/61682